# How to use same code in different projects

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

This is a more general question rather than an inquiry about a very specific technical point in some language. Imagine I write a set of very specific functions in VB.NET or maybe C# that take as input some data (say hourly temperature data) and perform complex calculations. Complex in the sense of many steps and checking conditions. So function A takes as input a matrix of 90x90 and spits out the determinant, for example, function B takes as input a part of that matrix and computes some average etc.

Now my question is this: how can I save the code behind these functions to be used in other projects? e.g. just like an Add-In in Excel. Would this be creating a DLL?I am using Visual Studio VB.NET. Should I make a console app and reference that (if so how?) in my future projects? I can write the code (currently transitioning from VBA) but I have a hard time to figure out this kind of "logistic" detail. Almost like a cook who knows the steps required to cook something but does not know his way around the kitchen:)

Thanks!

Comment: put them in a dll ?

Comment: You can create a Class library project, add your functions to it and compile it to an assembly that can then be referenced by other assemblies. You can optionally build a nuget package for it to make it easily available to consumers.

Comment: ...or even add the class / partial class / classes to a Project as a link to existing files. But, this case, the content of these files can be modified, of course, unless the files are read-only (Source Control notifies you when the read-only attribute is set on a file)

Comment: You want to create a class library for that code (a single project in a .net solution). You could then publish the library as a nuget package to re-use it elsewhere or could just copy that project into another solution and reference it there. Or you keep all your "business projects" in a single .net solution.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [What is a DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/dynamic-link-library) and [Dynamic-Link Libraries (Dynamic-Link Libraries)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-libraries).

Answer (score 1):

Create a class library project. That can be referenced by other projects in the same solution as a project reference, or outside the solution as a compiled dll.

For this simple example, in a project called ClassLibrary1, with this class

```cs
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        public static int PlusOne(int operand) => operand++;
        public static int MinusOne(int operand) => operand--;
    }
}
```

When adding a project reference, right click Dependencies and Add Project Reference...

In this case, the project using it will be WinFormsApp1

[image]

Choose ClassLibrary1

Then you can do this from within WinFormsApp1

```cs
var a = ClassLibrary1.Class1.PlusOne(0);
```

And you can also add a VB project the same way, and reference that class library again, and do

```vb
Dim a = ClassLibrary1.Class1.MinusOne(1)
```

If you build either of the apps, since the class library is a project reference, it will also be built automatically as needed. This is a benefit of using a project reference.

Say you don't want your class library project in the same solution as another project. Then you can directly reference the dll in the bin directory

[image]

It won't be built automatically when projects using it are referencing it so you will need to initiate a build manually

Answer (score 0):

The answer largely depends on what you need exactly. If your projects are to be running on the same machine, then you can create a class library project. Here's a tutorial to do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-8-0

But, it's possible that you will have multiple projects dependent on this one, perhaps scattered on different machines, maybe not even in your control. In such situations you might consider providing a DLL (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/creating-and-using-dll-class-library-in-C-Sharp/) to your clients or machines, or, you could build an API upon your functions (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) which accepts requests, interprets and sanitizes them, executes the corresponding calculation and responds with the result.

Comment: Thank you all for your great advices, especially djv & Arpad! It seems to me the bulletproof method to approach this method, in the end, is a DLL.

Comment: @StefanLiiceanu You can mark the answers you find helpful so that they can help more people